# Store socket response to a string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, sockets, ssl

I try to connect to a https URL an store the response to a string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
   PeerHost => "google.com",
   PeerPort => "https"
) or die "Error: $!";
print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
my $content = <$socket>;
print $content;
print "length: ";
print length($content);
print "\n";
close $socket;
```

The output is only the first line of the HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
length: 20
```

When I change the script and print the response with "print", the output is the complete repsonse:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
   PeerHost => "google.com",
   PeerPort => "https"
) or die "Error: $!";
print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
print <$socket>;
close $socket;
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=XAroVeuYDMWo8wfioYKQBw
Content-Length: 259
Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:52:44 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800

<HTML>...</HTML>
```

I do not understan why I cannot store the socket response to a string.

I use Perl v5.14.2

Comment: <$socket> will act differently depending on the context. A call to a handle in scalar context will return to you the next line from the handle. A call to the handle in list context will return to you every line. Print is list context where as assigning to a scalar is scaler context.

Comment: try `my $content = join('',<$socket>);`. Join will read `<$socket>` in list context then join each line together and return a single string, which can then be allocated to your scalar variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Chris Doyle is the solution for this problem:

> `<$socket>` will act differently depending on the context. A call to a
>   handle in scalar context will return to you the next line from the
>   handle. A call to the handle in list context will return to you every
>   line. Print is list context where as assigning to a scalar is scaler
>   context. –  Chris Doyle 10 mins ago
>
> try `my $content = join('',<$socket>);`. Join will read `<$socket>` in list 
>   context then join each line together and return a single string,
>   which can then be allocated to your scalar variable. –  Chris Doyle 8

Comment: Or: `my $content; { local $/; $content = <$socket>; }`